# install sonata ecommerce with composer.phar update

Tags: symfony, symfony-sonata

when i try to install sonata ecommerce with composer.phar update

> error [runtimeExeption] Could not load package
>   orange-opensource/orange-boosted-bootstrap in http://packagist.org:
>   [unexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint
>   v4.0.0-alpha.3.1 Invalid version string "v4.0.0-alpha.3.1" .

composer.json

```
{
"name": "symfony/framework-standard-edition",
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"description": "The \"Symfony Standard Edition\" distribution",
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.4,>=2.4.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.5.*",
     "twig/extensions": "1.2.*",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "symfony/security":  "@stable",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "@stable",
   "sensio/distribution-bundle": "4.0.*",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "3.0.*",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "2.3.*",
    "leafo/lessphp": "*",
    "twitter/bootstrap": "*",
    "friendsofsymfony/jsrouting-bundle": "@stable",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "@stable",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/comment-bundle":"@stable",
    "sonata-project/core-bundle": "@stable",
    "sonata-project/media-bundle": "2.3.3",
    "sonata-project/admin-bundle": "@stable",
    "sonata-project/doctrine-orm-admin-bundle": "@stable",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle": "@stable",        
    "sonata-project/translation-bundle": "~1",
    "a2lix/translation-form-bundle": "1.*@dev",
    "a2lix/i18n-doctrine-bundle": "^0.1.0",
    "jordillonch/crud-generator": "dev-master",
    "knplabs/doctrine-behaviors": "@stable",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "@stable",
    "sonata-project/user-bundle": "@stable",
    "fp/jsformvalidator-bundle":"@stable",
    "ensepar/html2pdf-bundle" : "@stable",
    "sonata-project/ecommerce": "@stable",
    "ibrows/newsletter-bundle": "*"

},
"scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
        "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "bin-dir": "bin"
},
"minimum-stability": "stable",
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "2.3-dev"
    }
}
```

}

Comment: can you post your composer.json file.

Comment: i joined composer.json in first comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your composer.json file seems fine - I was able to run it with "composer.phar update" without any issue.

Try updating composer with "composer.phar self-update" and clearing it's cache with "composer.phar clear-cache".

Comment: thanx you very much.